# Server script that sends a warning each time an error appears

Tags: looking-for-a-script, webserver

I have a managed VPS, and I share inside it a few domain accounts.
After one of those accounts run out of disk space, and a big fat error appeared in all other  accounts because of that, I asked the hosting to turn off the "eaccelerator" a feature that they´ve implemented for me to make my sites faster.

The thing is that I don't want this horrible problem to happen again, and I would like to have something that tells me if any error appears in any of my sites, maybe a SMS, or an email.

Is there any script that would allow you to do that?

Comment: What does eAccelerator have to do with the errors or one account running out of disk space?

Comment: The host told me that eAccelerator was the guilty script to be the culprit. They´ve told me something like this (it´s translated from spanish): "you haven´t any space left in that partition /tmp, that´s because eaccelerator was using too much disk. Is like a php cache, and it should boost the page rendering, letting all compiled php inside the disk, but sometimes is not good because while it reduces CPU usage, it boosts the usage of the disk. I´ve deactivated it to check how your VPS works without it".

Answer (score 1):

There are many IT monitoring platforms that should be able to do this. Probably the most popular and robust is [Nagios](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/Apache), which can be set up to monitor services as well as network hardware.

Though to prevent this sort of thing from happening in the future, you should use a bytecode caching PHP accelerator that's set to use different disk caches for different vhosts (it's possible eAccelerator can be configured to do this, as there seems to be a way to set different configurations for different vhosts), setting storage quotas for each user, and put each vhost in a separate user directory.

Also, eAccelerator doesn't *ever* clear its disk cache. It's up to you to run a cronjob that clears/refreshes the disk cache every once in a while. It doesn't seem very efficient, but that seems to be how it's designed. There should be other PHP accelerators that can delete old cached versions and only refresh the cache when the modified date has changed for a PHP file.